# Pushing to JS Object

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of strings and a separate array of booleans.

```
const strings = ['a','b','c'];
const bools = [true, false, false];
const obj = {};
```

How do I push these arrays to the obj so that I would get result of :

```
{a: true, b: true, c: false}
```

Comment: `['a':true]` is not valid JS syntax. `{['a':true]}` either.

Comment: The first suggestion is invalid. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: The goal remains the same, I guess then: ['a': true, 'b':false,'c':false]. I need an object :|

Comment: simple loop is all you need

Comment: @OliverRadini Your first example won't work ;)

Comment: @Adriani6 Thanks, removed that out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The most productive way**:

[image]

```js
const strings = ['a','b','c'];
const bools = [true, false, false];
let obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  obj[strings[i]] = bools[i]
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Try and avoid `for in`, and use `for of` instead..  And for that example try and avoid the use of a global `i`

Comment: A little do not understand you, you think that the `for of` will be better answer? `i` variable not such a problem in most cases.

Comment: `you think that the for of will be better`  Yes..  `i variable not such a problem in most cases` it is if it's a global variable, local variables are much faster than global,.  so `for (let i of strings)` should give you some speed back.  To be honest I should have maybe commented on thepieterdc, as I can see if you have just copy pasted his code.

Comment: Here is a code for `for of`? https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/yqmzbE?editors=0010 Why you think i'm using `i` like global variable? i'm using `let i` like in your `for (let i of strings)`

Comment: Your screenshot for jsperf shows -> `for (i in strings)`,.  and is likely why it's so much slower.  ps.  I should have maybe made it more obvious I was talking about the jsperf screenshot.. :)

Comment: clearly, I copied the answer and did not pay attention to it, but it seems that it does not affect, look at the result: https://i.imgur.com/aaxjDWT.png

Comment: please go in chat

Comment: I see what you have done, all sorted now..  :)   Not used `in` for so long now, forgot what it even did..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to obtain this result:

```
obj = {a:true, b:false, c:false}
```

This should work:

```js
const strings = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const bools = [true, false, false];
const obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
  obj[strings[i]] = bools[i];
}

console.log(obj); // outputs {a:true, b:false, c:false}
```

Comment: had to use normal for(let i = ... i++) but worked nonetheless, thanks

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько this means you cannot reassign the variable, you can still modify the object. Writing for example `const obj = {}; obj = {}` would not work.

Comment: You should never use `for in` for iterating an array

Comment: Updated in accordance with your post @ИльяЗеленько

Answer (score 0):

So you can't do exactly what you want as the structure you're after is invalid javascript, however you can produce semantically similar structures, a function which achieves the following result:

`{'a': true, 'b': true, 'c': true}`

Looks something like so:

```
const zipTwoArraysToObject = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.reduce((memo, item1, index) => {
  memo[item1] = arr2[index]
  return memo
}, {})
```

While a function that produces the following:

`[{'a': true}, {'b': true}, {'c': true}]`

would look like so:

```
const zipTwoArraysToArrayOfObjects = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.map((item1, index) => {
  const tempStore = {}
  tempStore[item1] = arr2[index]
  return tempStore
})
```

A runnable snippet of both in action:

```js
    const zipTwoArraysToObject = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.reduce((memo, item1, index) => {
      memo[item1] = arr2[index]
      return memo
    }, {})

    const zipTwoArraysToArrayOfObjects = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.map((item1, index) => {
      const tempStore = {}
      tempStore[item1] = arr2[index]
      return tempStore
    })

    const strings = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    const bools = [true, true, true]
    console.log('zipTwoArraysToObject', zipTwoArraysToObject(strings, bools))
    console.log('zipTwoArraysToArrayOfObjects', zipTwoArraysToArrayOfObjects(strings, bools))
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieved result, use forEach and index to loop through strings array and assign values to obj with bools array using index

```
const strings = ['a','b','c'];
const bools = [true, false, false];
const obj = {};

strings.forEach((v, i) => obj[v] = bools[i])

console.log(obj)
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/MBNvXE?editors=1010

```js
const strings = ['a','b','c'];
const bools = [true, false, false];
const obj = {};

strings.forEach((v, i) => obj[v] = bools[i])

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Why `map`? `map` is not intended to do side-effects.

Comment: forEach would work for looping, updating my answer, unless user want to modify strings to add or modify strings or bools array

Comment: I'd say map is fine, not sure of the side-effects issue,.. It's not a Douglas Crockford comment is it?.

Comment: @Keith functional programming usually implies no side effects.

Comment: @thepieterdc  If you are implementing functional programming that might be so,.  But seen as map generates a new array, what side effect are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce, in one line:

```
const strings = ['a','b','c'];
const bools = [true, false, false];

var obj = strings.reduce((x, y, z) => { x[y] = bools[z]; return x; }, {});

console.log(obj);
```